# Erlang compound boolean expression

Tags: erlang, boolean

I read the documentation about using `and`, `or` operators, but why is the following not evaluating?

```
X = 15,
Y = 20,
X==15 and Y==20.
```

I am expecting for a "true" in the terminal, but I get a "syntax error before ==".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
X = 15.
Y = 20.
(X==15) and (Y==20).
```

Answer (score 8):

You probably don't want to use and.   There are two problems with and, firstly as you've noticed its precedence is strange, secondly it doesn't short circuit its second argument.

```
1> false and exit(oops).
** exception exit: oops
2> false andalso exit(oops).
false
```

andalso was introduced later to the language and behaves in the manner which is probably more familiar.  In general, use andalso unless you have a good reason to prefer and.

Btw, orelse is the equivalent of or.

Comment: It really depends on whether you are using it for control or boolean tests. Using and/or has the benefit of testing the return values of the "boolean" operations.

Answer (score 5):

Without braces you can also do

```
X = 15.
Y = 20.
X == 15 andalso Y == 20.
```

Answer (score 2):

herre's the operator precedence / binding rules table, for future reference

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id2274242

============

here's some erlang "gotcha" lists i found helpful

[Learning Erlang? speedbump thread, common, small problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430726/learning-erlang-speedbump-thread-common-small-problems)

http://www.erlang.org/faq/problems.html

http://baphled.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/lighting-up-the-tunnerl-pt-3-afterl-the-basics/

http://baphled.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/lighting-up-the-tunnerl-pt-9-the-gotchaz/